# Why does my computer switch to default speakers when someone calls me on Skype?

Tags: audio, skype

I was listening to a Youtube video with my head phones in a library.

Suddenly, when someone called me on Skype, the audio reverted to the computer's default speakers, blasting the Skype call ring and my Youtube video to a bunch of people quietly trying to read their books.

Strangely, the headphones were still attached to the computer jack.

Why does my computer switch to computer speakers when someone calls me on Skype?

Comment: Let me guess windows 7?  Hey why am I guessing?? what OS?

Comment: Yes, Windows 7.

Comment: Do your headphones connect with the normal audio jack (3mm) or do they use a USB connector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Skype client you configure your audio devices under Call-Audio Settings.  Check what you have configured.  I think default is to play the "ring" on all devices.

Comment: also check in winders "sounds" in the "comunications" tab. I have no idea how/if that effects skype, I dont use it.

Comment: Thank you, that did it! The choice "Use selected speaker" stops Skype from changing speakers.